# Django1.4: How to use order_by in template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-2.7, django-1.4

Django1.4: How to use order_by in template?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic

class Note(models.Model):
    contents = models.TextField()
    writer = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field='username')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')


class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,)
    notes = generic.GenericRelation(Note, null=True)
```

Above is my models.py.

I want to use 'order_by'([https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)

And...

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from crm.models import *

class customerDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'customerDetail'
    template_name = "customerDetail.html"
    allow_empty = True
    model = Customer
    slug_field = 'name'
```

My views.py use DetailView(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/class-based-views/#detailview).

And

customerDetail.html

```
<table class="table table-bordered" style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>Note</td>
    </tr>
    {% for i in customerDetail.notes.all.order_by %}<!-- It's not working -->
        <tr>
            <th>({{ i.date }}) {{ i.contents }}[{{ i.writer }}]</th>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

I want to use order_by in template...

What should I do?

Comment: have you tried `queryset = Customer.objects.order_by()` in `customerDetailView`?

Comment: Yeah, I tried `queryset = Customer.objects.order_by('note__date')` and `queryset = Customer.objects.order_by('note__date')`. But failed...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The order_by needs at least one argument, and Django does not allow you to pass arguments to a function or method inside a template.

Some alternatives are:

- Use [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) template engine instead of Django's one (Jinja2 will let you pass arguments to methods and is said to perform better)
- order the dataset in the view
- use the "[Meta:ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering)" attribute to define a default ordering criteria for your models
- write a custom filter so you can `queryset|order_by:'somefield'` ([see this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/741/))
- as suggested by [Michal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225718/michal-cihar), you can write a [custom Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/) with predefined methods for the orderings you need

Comment: ...or use custom Manager for the class which will provide you predefined ways of ordering

Comment: I don't know understand fourth tip "write a custom filter so you can `queryset|order_by:'somefield'`". Could you give me ... some example code?

Comment: Anyway I solved it. `class Meta:
  ordering = ['date']` (in models.py)

Comment: cathy answer has such sample code, seems like she is using the same [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/741/) (but she forgot to attribute the solution to the [original author](http://djangosnippets.org/users/marinho/)). Also, you need to place this file in [some specific location](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) in order to be able to load it inside the template.

Comment: @chobo regarding the fourth tip, you may use the link he has provided or refer to this link. https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/create-custom-template-tags-and-filters-in-django . The fourth tip worked for me

Answer (score 14):

Check out the [dictsort](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#dictsort) filter, it's pretty much what you're looking for I think.

Comment: This is the easiest answer and it does work on querysets.